# How to add multiple onclick events to all elements in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I've a HTML code like this.

```
<a onclick="prompt('Complete','Lorem');">Lorem</a>
<a onclick="prompt('Complete','ipsum');">ipsum</a>
<a onclick="prompt('Complete','dolor');">dolor</a>
<a onclick="prompt('Complete','sit');">sit</a>
<a onclick="prompt('Complete','amet');">amet</a>
...
```

I want to minify HTML code, like this: `<a>Lorem</a><a>ipsum</a>`
How can I add onclick prompt event to all clickable elements in a page? as in the above code. Is it possible?

Comment: Read about [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.addEventListener).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JavaScript, you have to attach the click handler to each item with a loop.

```js
function userPrompt(event){
  prompt("Complete " + event.target.innerText);
}
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', userPrompt));
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<a>Lorem</a>
<a>ipsum</a>
<a>dolor</a>
<a>sit</a>
<a>amet</a>
```

JQuery has a simple way of achieving this.

```js
function userPrompt(event){
  prompt("Complete " + event.target.innerText);
}

$('a').on('click', userPrompt);
```

```css
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a>Lorem</a>
<a>ipsum</a>
<a>dolor</a>
<a>sit</a>
<a>amet</a>
```

Comment: plus one for the non jquery and jquery examples

Answer (score 1):

Like pointed out, addEventListener is your friend here.

One major advantange of addEventListener compared to say a normal onClick, is that any elements added to the DOM later will also be taken into account, and is also possible to add multiple event listeners to the same element.

Below is a simple example.  I basically add the eventListener to the body, filter out any elements that are not A links, and then show a prompt for the user to change the innerText of this element.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  //lets limit to just A links
  if (e.target.tagName !== "A") return;
  const ret = prompt("Confirm", e.target.innerText);
  if (ret !== null) {
    e.target.innerText = ret;
  }
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>Click a link to change the innerText</div>

<a>Lorem</a>
<a>ipsum</a>
<a>dolor</a>
<a>sit</a>
<a>amet</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// select all <a> tags
document.querySelectorAll('a')
  // loop over them
  .forEach(a =>
    // append the event by calling addEventListener
    a.addEventListener('click', () => window.prompt('Complete', 'Lorem')))
```

The `forEach` can take a second argument, the index, so you can define the message on each prompt according to the value of an array.

```
const promptValue = [
  'Lorem',
  'ipsum',
  'dolor',
  'sit',
  'amet'
]

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((a, i) =>
  a.addEventListener('click', () => window.prompt('Complete', promptValue[i])))
```

**Edit:** I should probably add that this may become hard to maintain if the list changes order in the future, so it's probably better to keep some reference to the prompt value in the HTML, even if it gets verbose. Nevertheless, it's bad to keep *scripts* in the HTML, so a data attribute might be a better approach.

**HTML**:

```
<a data-prompt="Lorem">Lorem</a>
<a data-prompt="ipsum">ipsum</a>
<a data-prompt="dolor">dolor</a>
<a data-prompt="sit">sit</a>
<a data-prompt="amet">amet</a>
```

**JS**:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a =>
  a.addEventListener('click', () => window.prompt('Complete', a.dataset.prompt)))
```